# Query not returning results as expected

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT  id AS "CLIENT CODE",name AS "CLIENT NAME",(
                            SELECT
                                count(status)
                            FROM
                                campaigns
                            WHERE
                                clientid = clients.id
                            ) AS "TOTAL CAMPAIGNS"
FROM    clients
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  clientid
        FROM    campaigns
        WHERE   status IN ('L', 'P')
        )
        AND id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  clientid
        FROM    campaigns
        WHERE   status NOT IN ('L', 'P')
        );
```

Now I have a clients table with all clients and a campaigns table with a status column that contains values of either L,C,P,?,X. Now one client can have 1 or more rows from campaigns. So with other words a client can have more than one campaigns with status values assigned to a campaign. Of either L,C,P,?,X

What I want the query to return to me is clients with campaigns where the status is L and P and not only P and not only L but both L and P. At the moment the query returns client that either have P or L or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should ensure that it has both

```
WHERE   id IN 
        ( 
        SELECT  clientid 
        FROM    campaigns 
        WHERE   status IN ('L') 
        ) 
    AND id  IN 
        ( 
        SELECT  clientid 
        FROM    campaigns 
        WHERE   status IN ('P') 
        )
```

Or even try [Subqueries with EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  clientid 
        FROM    campaigns 
        WHERE   status IN ('L') 
        AND     clientid = client.id
        )    
    AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  clientid 
        FROM    campaigns 
        WHERE   status IN ('P') 
        AND     clientid = client.id
        )
```

Comment: Thx, this is really helpful, and the logic worked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

> I would re-write your query the
>   following way:
>
> SELECT  id AS "CLIENT CODE",name AS
>
> "CLIENT NAME",(
>
> ```
>                         SELECT
>                             count(*)             //count all
>                         FROM
>                             campaigns
>                         WHERE
>                             clientid = clients.id
> ```
>
> ) AS "TOTAL CAMPAIGNS" FROM  clients
>
> WHERE   id IN
>
> (
>           SELECT  clientid
>
> ```
>     FROM    campaigns
>
>     WHERE   status='L'
>
>     )
>
>     AND id 
>
>     (
>
>     SELECT  clientid
>
>     FROM    campaigns
>
>     WHERE   status='P'
>
>
>     );
> ```

What I am not sure is about the final variable called total campaigns, what do you wanna put there the total amount of campaigns? if so it is correct what I wrote, but if your idea is another please re-explain it to me and I will answer again.