# Select all rows that have the tag X and Y for filter results

Tags: mysql

Here I have a problem that seems to be easy to solve but I can't find the solution. I need to select all rows that have the *tag* X and Y in the table *tags* grouped by product.

Tags

+---------+------+

| product | tag  |

+---------+------+

| 1       | x    |

+--+--+

| 1       | y    |

+--+--+

| 2       | y    |

+--+--+

| 2       | z    |

+--+--+

| 3       | x    |

+--+--+

| 3       | y    |

+--+--+

So, in this case the rows to be selected are for the product 1 and 3 becasuse both have the tag X and Y

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Have a look at something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162445/query-not-returning-results-as-expected/4162486#4162486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT product
    FROM tags
   WHERE tag IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY product
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I don't udestand very well why you set having count(*)=2

Comment: @betus: because you have 2 tags. If you'll search for 3 tags - then there will be number 3.

Comment: @betus: the short explanation: `IN(..)` gets us all records that fits any of searching item. so for `IN('x', 'y')` clause there can be products with only `x`, with only `y` and withboth  `x and y`. Since we need only last case - we grouping records by product and filtering only ones, that have exactly 2 matches. I hope this is detailed enough, is not it?

Comment: @betus: nice to hear ;-) Btw, if you show your current table schema, I can help improve it a little more. I think it is one redundant index there now (post the schema to your initial question)

Comment: anyway I have made the index like you said CREATE INDEX tag_product ON tags (tag, product); is it ok?

Comment: what's the difference in having two indexes for each one that having one for both?

Comment: @betus: yes, it is ok. But now you don't need index, that covers single tag field, because `tag_product` index also covers it.

Comment: yes I have already deleted the indexes before creating this one! ;)

Comment: @betus: mysql can use only one index per query. So if you have for example condition `WHERE a=1 AND b=2` - and you have 2 separate indexes `a` and `b` - then mysql will decide which index is better to use, and use **only one** of them. So rows will be searched by index, and after that they will be **fullscanned** to check the left part of condition. But if you have index `a+b` - then mysql will use it and find the values immediately. This topic is **very complex**, but that is how it works in glance.

Comment: @betus: "yes I have already deleted the **indexes**" --- if you have any queries that depend on `WHERE product = 666` - then you need to bring back single `product` index. Because the order is important index `tag+product` covers single `tag` as well as `tag+price`, but doesn't cover single `product`. So as result you will have two indexes: `product` and `tag+product`.

Comment: ok, then I will have to create it again because I search here for product and for tag. So I need 3 indexes now!

Comment: @betus: no. You need 2 indexes: `product` and `tag+product`

Comment: @betus: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html Read from the words "If the table has a multiple-column index" to the end of paragraph.

Comment: @betus: yes, and queries like `WHERE tag = 'foo'` **will be optimized** by using `tag+product`, because `tag` field in this composite index is its leftmost part (look again at the documentation). If you have index `a+b+c` you don't need to create indexes `a` or `a+b`, because `a+b+c` **contains** them as leftmost part.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something similar to this...

```
SET @tags := 'X,Y';

SELECT product, tag
FROM tags
GROUP BY product
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag ORDER BY tag SEPARATOR ',') = @tags;
```